# where to put external assets in ruby on rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

If I have Javascrips/CSS files from an ASP .NET Project and I want to put them in my Rails project. Where's the best place to put them? Do I need to change every url into `<%= asset_path "img" %>`?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in assets folder and add below line in views:

To add CSS files:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "test.css" %>
```

To add JavaScript files:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'test.js'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Unknown's answer:

Yes, you do need to use `asset_path`, or one of the sprocket helpers, to refer to your assets in your CSS file so that they will properly include the MD5 fingerprint. Plus, this way you get the right asset between development and production (since they don't live in public while in development). Here's the relevant guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Answer (score 0):

According to http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html

The best practise for DRY and speed (according to article above) is to download all files to your projects assets folders, put them in the assets pipe for each application.js/.css and let rails compile them into one application.js and application.css in production mode. There are several ways to do this in detail (see link) The preferred way according to article for speed and DRY-practise is to call all js and css from application.css/.js and not put stylesheet_link_tag, calling css or js from view-files. This even though you may have one specific user.js which you only want to use on users page. Though there are ways to load specific files into specific views (see article for details)
Ecxept from having to call them in once in head of application.html(.haml/.erb):

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

If you are calling files in css eg. an image, as long as you have the image in "assets/images" you only need to refer to the images as 'image.jpg' in your css/js-files.